# How to handle Sql Server rollbacks when Azure service bus message fails to save on the queue and they depend on each other?

Tags: azure, exception, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm saving a row to my db (class with teacher/students, time, date, etc), once I have the id I create a message on my Azure service bus where the unique id of the row from my db is used as the message body of the service bus message. I'm creating scheduled messages so I can notify the students before the class and after the class is over so they can rate/review their teacher.

**QUESTION** - I'd like to know how to roll back or an easy way to remove the db row by not allowing it to fully save if the message to the Azure service bus fails to save?

Currently I'm using a generic repository with UnitOfWork to save to my db and I'm catching the exception from my service bus service if it fails, then deleting the row that was just saved, but it's sloppy looking and I can see it will lead to problems.

Here is what I'm doing now in the controller.

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnCreating(OnCreatingEventDto onCreatingDto)
    {
        var userFromRepo = await _userManager.FindByEmailFromClaimsPrinciple(HttpContext.User);
        
        if (userFromRepo == null) 
            return Unauthorized(new ApiResponse(401));

        var newEvent = _mapper.Map<ClassEvent>(onCreatingDto);

        _unitOfWork.Repository<ClassEvent>().Add(newEvent);

        var success = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
        if (success > 0) {

            try {
                var sequenceNUmber = await _serviceBusProducer.SendMessage(newEvent.Id.ToString(), newEvent.eventTime.addDays(1), queueName);
                newEvent.ServiceBusSequenceNumber = sequenceNUmber;
                _unitOfWork.Repository<ClassEvent>().Update(newEvent);

                var secondSuccess = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
                if (secondSuccess > 0) {
                    return Ok();
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                _logger.LogError("error saving to service bus");
                _unitOfWork.Repository<ClassEvent>().Delete(newEvent);
                var deleteSuccess = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
                if (deleteSuccess > 0) {

                }
                return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Problem Creating Event"));
            }
            
        }

        return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Problem Creating Event"));
        
    }
```

Here is the method from my service that creates the message on the queue

```
    public async Task<long> SendMessage(string messageBody, DateTimeOffset scheduledEnqueueTime, string queueName)
    {
        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(_config["ServiceBus:Connection"]))
        {
            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(_config["ServiceBus:" + queueName]);

            ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(messageBody);

            var sequenceNumber = 
            await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, scheduledEnqueueTime);
            
            return sequenceNumber;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you not split this in 2 parts? Essentially your code should simply try to write to Service Bus. Once the message is written in Service Bus, you can insert the data in SQL Server by triggering an Azure Function.

Comment: Another approach is to look into a messaging middleware that has already solved that problem with a pattern such as [outbox](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/) pattern.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. I thought about writing to the service bus first, I could get the sequence number and store that in the db row with the other properties and then use that to look up the event after I my consumer receives the message on it's scheduled time. But if I do this first, then the db add row fails, I have to go and delete the message out of the bus queue. So it seems like there are multiple follow up actions needed regardless of what I do first. DB or service bus...

Comment: `But if I do this first, then the db add row fails, I have to go and delete the message out of the bus queue` - If you're using a Service Bus Queue triggered Function, you don't have to do anything other than successfully returning from your Function. The Function infrastructure will take care of deleting the message for you.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Do you mean triggering a function after the message is placed in the queue? If yes, remember this is a website that has to give feedback to the client/user that shows the students class/event was created successfully. I don't think I'd be able to do that if all the work was done in a Azure function separate from the ASP.Net Core app

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you mean by a Service Bus Queue triggered Function? Do you mean a function that runs in Azure, apart from my ASP.Net Core app or is this some type of function that runs in my app?